# Can I use a Triggered File Drop Automation with an External FTP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, triggered-send, import

Can I use a triggered file drop automation with an External sFTP?

Within Automation Studio I have the Starting Source set to File Drop and the Step One Activity as an Import Activity>ImportFile>File Location*=[MyExternalsFTP]

Will it be able to actively 'watch' this External sFTP locaiton for when a file appears in it?

The file drop seems a little ambiguous when selecting a directory.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  It seems that the file drop automation entry is only able to look at the Enhanced FTP of the business unit or the Triggered Automations folder, which from the documentation looks like it's just the Legacy name for the Import folder

Comment: Can you comment on the use case you are trying to achieve? Maybe there are some scripts you can invoke on the server side part which can help you (bash / powershell / batch / python, ..)

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only use the triggered automations on the Enhanced ExactTarget SFTP. External SFTPs can be used for File Transfers.